# Translation Golf XLIII - De bello Hispaniensi

Tags: traducción, translation-golf

For this edition of Translation Golf, the original text is in Latin (English translations also supplied!), attributed to Julius Caesar. It's from near the end of the description of a military campaign in Spain which finished the civil war that began when Caesar crossed the Rubicon.

---

[De bello Hispaniensi, 39](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/caesar/hisp.shtml):

> Pompeius, ut supra demonstravimus, saucius et intorto talo idcirco tardabatur ad fugiendum, itemque propter loci difficultatem neque equo neque vehiculo saluti suae praesidium parare poterat. Caedes a nostris undique administrabatur. Exclusus a munitione amissisque auxiliis ad convallem exesumque locum in speluncam Pompeius se occultare coepit, ut a nostris non facile inveniretur nisi captivorum indicio. Ita ibi interficitur. Cum Caesar Gadibus fuisset, Hispalim pridie Idus Apriles caput adlatum et populo datum est in conspectum.
>
> <sub>(453 characters.)</sub>

[English translation by W. A. McDevitte and W. S. Bohn](http://classics.mit.edu/Caesar/spanish.html):

> Pompey as we have observed above being lame and wounded, was in no condition to make a speedy retreat; and the rather, because the place was such that he could use neither horse nor litter. Slaughter was dealt on all hands by our troops, his fortress having been stormed, and his resources cut off. In this extremity he fled to a cave, where he could not easily be discovered, unless by the information of the captives. Here he was slain, his head was brought to Hispalis on the day before the ides of April, and exhibited before the people when Caesar was at Gades.
>
> <sub>(450 characters.)</sub>

[Spanish translation (anonymous)](https://www.imperivm.org/cont/textos/txt/julio-cesar_comentarios-de-la-guerra-civil-oc-iii.html):

> Pompeyo herido, como se ha dicho, y torcido un pie, no podía huir muy de prisa, y por lo escabroso del terreno, ni a caballo ni en la litera encontraba auxilio para salvarse. Los nuestros, perdido el fuerte y sus auxilios, corrían libremente las espadas por los enemigos. Pompeyo fue a refugiarse a una hondonada de un valle en una caverna a modo de gruta, adonde no le hallaran tan fácilmente los nuestros si no fuera descubierto por unos prisioneros; allí le mataron. Estando César en Cádiz el día 12 de abril, se trajo su cabeza a Sevilla, y se expuso a la vista de la ciudad.

My own translation:

> Pompeyo, como hemos mostrado arriba, estaba herido y con el tobillo torcido, lo cual le impidió huir, y además el terreno dificultaba que ni caballo ni litera pudiera conseguir la defensa de su seguridad. La carnicería fue administrada por todos lares por los nuestros. En la extremidad de haber perdido su fortificación y sus ayudas, Pompeyo empezó a esconderse en una cueva de un valle, donde no le encontráramos fácilmente si no fuera por indicaciones de parte de los cautivos. Allí le mataron. Con César en Cádiz, su cabeza fue llevado a Sevilla en la víspera del idus de abril y dado al pueblo para verlo.

Notes:

- I've generally stuck to passives even when they're not very natural in Spanish. Your translation doesn't have to.
- Key points:

  1. The subject is Pompey. His name should appear at least once.
  2. He is prevented from fleeing (on foot) by his injuries
  3. The terrain means that he can't flee by other means (horse or vehicle)
  4. "Our" (i.e. Caesar's) troops were executing carnage.
  5. Pompey had lost his fortifications and his aid
  6. He hid in a cave
  7. Where he was found only by information gathered from prisoners
  8. That's where he was killed
  9. His head was exhibited publicly in Seville

---

The goal is to translate the given text to Spanish, using as few letters as possible, while keeping all the original text's meaning and concepts more or less intact.

- See the [rules](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/5481).
- Here's the [letter counter](https://jsfiddle.net/2ermv0rh/2/embedded/result/)

Comment: Duda histórica: ¿son sinónimas _Gades_ y _Cádiz_, así como _Hispalis_ y _Sevilla_? Pensé que Hispalis era la villa romana origen de Sevilla, pero que actualmente está algo separada de la ciudad.

Comment: @fedorqui "Hispalis" es el nombre que recibía la propia Sevilla en la época de los romanos. De hecho a esta muchas veces se la denomina "la capital [hispalense](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KVeSQKs)". Igualmente Gades era el nombre romano de Cádiz, de ahí el gentilicio "[gaditano](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Igy6b13)". La ciudad romana que está cerca de Sevilla pero no es Sevilla es [Itálica](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%A1lica).

Comment: @Charlie sí, he oído con frecuencia el uso de _hispalense_, _gaditano_ y muchos más. Sin embargo, me sonaba la existencia de casos donde la ciudad romana no coincidía ([Numancia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numancia) para Soria, por ejemplo). ¡Gracias por confirmar que en este caso sí es correcto!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### 121

<sup><sub>5</sub></sup>[Desvalido](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DX4myLA), <sup><sub>3</sub></sup>[impedido](http://dle.rae.es/?w=impedido) por el terreno <sup><sub>2</sub></sup>y su pie, <sup><sub>1</sub></sup>Pompeyo huyó <sup><sub>4</sub></sup>de la masacre <sup><sub>6</sub></sup>[encovándose](http://dle.rae.es/?id=F9sOCgP). <sup><sub>7</sub></sup>Los presos se [chivaron](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8uvSNZT) y <sup><sub>8</sub></sup>allí [palmó](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RZmjYFt%7CRZo9nMx). <sup><sub>9</sub></sup>Su [testa](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZecEwPE) se mostró en Sevilla.

Answer (score 5):

#### 190 characters

> Con Pompeyo cojo, su huida fue lenta: ni caballo ni litera y con terreno [abrupto](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0BuJHDZ). Sin fuerte ni suministros, les masacramos. Se ocultó en una cueva, mas le delataron [captivos](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7MHniQ4) y fue muerto. Con César en Cádiz, su cabeza se exhibió en Sevilla.